# Is it possible to left align SearchView in AppCompat 21 with toolbar?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview, material-design

I want to left align the SearchView on tablets when using the new material theme and AppCompat 21. Is this possible or must I add my own custom layout to the toolbar?

[image]

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    mnuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mnuSearch);
    searchView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
    searchView.requestFocus();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: very good question buddy
I guess in the body of toolbar in your the xml you can set the icon using image view 
you can try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather define your `SearchView` in a layout and then call

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.your_search_view);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

This way it comes already aligned on the left, and if it doesn't you can set its `LayoutParams`.

If you're using a `Toolbar` with AppCompat things are easier, because it acts as a `ViewGroup`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:abc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <your.SearchView />
        // here you have control over layout_gravity

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks, will do it this way. Had hoped for an easy fix but I guess this is as easy as it gets :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used searchview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:gravity="start"
                app:searchIcon="@mipmap/icon_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            <TextView
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:text="title"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```